# Rearrange equation using Maxima

Tags: maxima

In Maxima I have an equation that is like:

```
eq : c0*a + d0*a + c1*b - c2*p - c4*q = c5*r
```

Is there a command that allows me to arrive at:

```
(c0 + d0)*a + c1*b = c2*p + c4*q + c5*r
```

In short, I want to choose which variables end on either the left or right hand side and I want to write it such that there is only one occurence of the variables I select (in this case a, b, p, q, r).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `coefmatrix` is useful for this.

```
(%i1) display2d : false $
(%i2) eq : c0*a + d0*a + c1*b - c2*p - c4*q = c5*r $
(%i3) vars : [a, b, p, q, r] $
(%i4) coeffs : coefmatrix ([eq], vars);
(%o4) matrix([d0+c0,c1,-c2,-c4,-c5])
(%i5) coeffs . vars;
(%o5) (-c5*r)-c4*q-c2*p+a*(c0+d0)+b*c1
```

Note that both arguments of `coefmatrix` must be lists.

Comment: it helps, but it is not enough yet, because it does not allow me to choose the lhs and rhs of a variable and therefore only solves half of my problem.

Comment: @Chiel what about `coeffs . [a,b,0,0,0]=-coeffs . [0,0,p,q,r];`?